# pass parameter to mapRow

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

i need to pass a parameter to my RowMapper because i need to apply timezone to date field. Currently this is my code:

Query:

```
@Override
    public List<GCProjectMember> selectGCMembers(Long jobId,String timezone) {

        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBeanBuilder.getClientDataSource(ClientContextHolder.getCustomerType(),
                this.getClass().getName());
        this.setDataSource(dataSource);

        List<GCProjectMember> membersList = getJdbcTemplate().query(SELECT_GC_MEMBERS, new Object[] { jobId },
                new GCProjectMemberRowMapper());
        if (membersList.size() > 0) {
            return membersList;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

RowMapper:

```
public class GCProjectMemberRowMapper extends BasicRowMapper implements RowMapper<GCProjectMember> {

    @Override
    public GCProjectMember mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        GCProjectMember member = new GCProjectMember();
        ...
        if (hasColumn(rs, "sign_date")) {
            member.setSignDate(rs.getTimestamp("sign_date"));
        }

        ....
        return member;
    }

}
```

How can i pass a timezone from query to rowmapper?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a parametrized constructor inside GCProjectMemberRowMapper and pass the timezone value to it while initializing the object.

```
public class GCProjectMemberRowMapper extends BasicRowMapper implements RowMapper<GCProjectMember> {

   private TimeZone timezone;

   public GCProjectMemberRowMapper(TimeZone timezone) {
     this.timezone = timezone
   }
   @Override
   public GCProjectMember mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    GCProjectMember member = new GCProjectMember();
    ...
    if (hasColumn(rs, "sign_date")) {
        member.setSignDate(rs.getTimestamp("sign_date"));
    }
    // use timezone here
    ....
    return member;
}
```

Can change the calling code like this.

```
@Override
public List<GCProjectMember> selectGCMembers(Long jobId,String timezone) {

    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBeanBuilder.getClientDataSource(ClientContextHolder.getCustomerType(),
            this.getClass().getName());
    this.setDataSource(dataSource);

    List<GCProjectMember> membersList = getJdbcTemplate().query(SELECT_GC_MEMBERS, new Object[] { jobId },
            new GCProjectMemberRowMapper(timezone));
    if (membersList.size() > 0) {
        return membersList;
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```